# How can I set clean urls (enable rewrite) if I don't have a domain?

Tags: lighttpd, drupal

In order to enable clean urls in Drupal, I add the lines below to the lighttpd configuration file.

However I'm now working on a local server and I don't have a domain available. So I need to work with this address 192.168.75.159:81/Sites/drupal/

I've tried to replace ["host"] with ["socket"] and replace the domain with ip and subfolders (see address above), but unsuccessfully. How can I set the configuration file to set clean urls even if I don't have a domain ?

thanks

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)mywebsite\.com" {
  server.document-root = "/var/www/sites/mywebsite"
  server.errorlog = "/var/log/lighttpd/mywebsite/error.log"
  server.name = "mywebsite.com"
  accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/mywebsite/access.log"
  include_shell "./drupal-lua-conf.sh mywebsite.com"

  url.access-deny += ( "~", ".inc", ".engine", ".install", ".info",
       ".module", ".sh", "sql", ".theme",
       ".tpl.php", ".xtmpl", "Entries",
       "Repository", "Root" )


  # "Fix" for Drupal SA-2006-006, requires lighttpd 1.4.13 or above
  # Only serve .php files of the drupal base directory
  $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/.*/.*\.php$" {
      fastcgi.server = ()
      url.access-deny = ("")
  }

  magnet.attract-physical-path-to = ("/etc/lighttpd/drupal-lua-scripts/p-.lua")

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what OS you are using but you can add a line to /etc/hosts on *nix systems and c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts that allow you to map mywebsite.com (or dev.mywebsite.com) to 127.0.0.1.

Or a better idea would be if you are in control of DNS just create a subdomain A record like dev.mywebsite.com and point it to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Not sure my question was clear. I've actually done what you wrote but it doesn't work. I've replaced $HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)mywebsite\.com" with $HTTP["host"] =~ "192.168.75.159:81/Sites/drupal/"

Comment: I don't think you understand my response, what you would do is "trick" your computer into using a hostname but point the hostname wherever you want. So, I think instead of 127.0.0.1 you probably want 192.168.75.159. And even if you put the record into DNS - it doesn't mean that other people will be able to access it, which I think is the easiest way.